# Unknown effect applied

Tags: modeling, texturing

I applied an unknown effect (metallic look?) to these faces(probably by hotkey), even I delete a face and rebuild on same vertices or change another material, they still look like this, please tell how to remove and become pure grey like the lower part, many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your normals?

Comment: As mqbaka mqbaka says it may be inverted normals, or inner faces, overlapping vertices... maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi, I uploaded here,https://pasteall.org/blend/1e07191cf3114a3d82727c2364cefd96

Comment: Right-click and select Shade Flat in Object mode will sort that. However there are definitely oddities with that file! Were the three meshes originally seperate objects which you've joined with CTRL - J? - The faces of the cube are all inverted as is the rectangle on top of the middle mesh, but I'd expect all three meshes to show shading problems if they were all one object when shade smooth was applied unless it was just done to the middle mesh in Edit mode. - Not something you could do by accident!

Comment: It works for my uploaded file, thanks! probably I did too much copy paste for this file, and I tried many different shade smooth in different way(edit/object mode), sometimes I forgot to undo the test.... anyway, thanks again~